# Parse Date Time

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

Below is the Date Time format I am getting from an API.

> Mon Apr 14 03:31:15 +0000 2014

How can I convert it to `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` Format.

I tried following code:

```
Dim strDate as String = "Mon Apr 14 03:31:15 +0000 2014"
Dim dateT as DateTime = DateTime.Parse(strDate)
```

I am getting following issue:

> DateTime.Parse(strDate)    {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

Any solution and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Try using `DateTime.ParseExact` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try using `ParseExact`.

Comment: what is '+0000' in your date time ?

Comment: If you want to hurt whoever output the date in that format, be my guest, in fact feel free to deliver an extra blow in the nads from me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact like:

```
string str = "Mon Apr 14 03:31:15 +0000 2014";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, 
                           "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more information see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For converting the parsed date to your required format do:

```
string formattedOutput = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

VB equivalent would be:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str,
                           "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim formattedOutput As String = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: +0000 is a time offset and can be parsed as `zzz` so it should be `"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`

Comment: @KonradKokosa, thanks for the great info, This is something new for me.

Answer (score -1):

string Date = (Convert.ToDateTime(control.Text)).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")

string Date = (Convert.ToDateTime(control.Text)).ToShortDateString();

you may also research  using a culture e.g

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="lab.aspx.cs" Inherits="lab"   MasterPageFile="~/Master.master"      Culture="en-CA" UICulture="en-CA" %>
```

Comment: Are you sure those `ToDateTime` will work with the specified format that the OP is receiving?